# Get the root URL for a Django aplication running with Apache WSGI

Tags: django, wsgi

I am running an Django application with Apache WSGI in http://localhost/myApplication.

How can I get the root path meaning: http://localhost/myApplication . From the documentation I can see that the request object has get_host() but this returns localhost and I cannot see anything to return the root path. I don't want to use anything on the settings because that would force me to change the settings if I change the path in the WSGI Apache configuration.

Any idea is much appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to get this path? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: This is why: The Django application has the settings variable called STATIC_URL with "/static/" and this is used to load static content like css, js and images. However if I mount this app in http://localhost/myApplication this will force me to modify STATIC_URL and I don't want to do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get it on a per request basis by accessing `request.META['SCRIPT_NAME']`. Because it is on a per request basis only, it is of no use in the Django settings file.